# sudo su not working correctly inside a bash script

Tags: bash, sudo

I have a script to setup a machine that need to change to another user. Unfortunately, I get a "permission denied" after the su command.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script executed from /home/foo/
touch hi_foo
cd /home/bar
sudo bar
touch hi_bar <-- permission denied
```

Any idea of a workaround? My script works well if I copy and paste it in the command line.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
#!/bin/bash
# script executed from /home/foo/
touch hi_foo
cd /home/bar
su bar touch hi_bar
```

you need to run your script with *sudo* so the process running your script will have sufficient rights to run *su bar command*